# Movie or show where people travel through bubbling dirty water, and, if caught in a bubble, turn into a monster/zombie

Tags: story-identification, horror

Saw this in the mid 90s as a young kid, possibly around '96 or '97 from what I recall; it seemed like 90s production value.

Don't remember the context just one scene: a mother (?) and her kids and their friends (?) are traveling through a room flooding with dirty water that is violently bubbling, large bubbles about a meter wide. As they swim across, one kid gets engulfed by a bubble and when he reappears he is a monster and they keep swimming. I am confident it was a movie but it could have been a television show, but given the context if it was a tv show i would think it would be a series of one-shots like Tales From The Crypt.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) for list of details you might include.